# Nginx URL rewrite to directory name shows no changes

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I've been trying to rewrite some Nginx location urls but can't get it to work.

For the directory structure `/dir1/dir2/index.html`, where I will have several different `dir2` directories and `dir1` is just for organizational purposes, I want to rename the urls to:

```
mysite.com/dir2
```

This is my best guess.

```
location ~ /dir1.*$ {
    rewrite ^/dir1/(.*)/.*$ mysite.com/$1 break;
}
```

I've tried several variations on this, and I can't get anything to change at all. Clicking on the link just results in:

```
mysite.com/dir1/dir2/index.html
```

Here is the full config:

```
server {

      root /var/www/website;
      index index.html;

      server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;

      location / {
              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }

      location ~ ^/dir1.*$ {
              rewrite ^/dir1/(.*)/.*$ mysite.com/$1 break;
      }

      listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
      listen 443 ssl;
      ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem; 
      include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
      ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
  }

  server {
      if ($host = www.mysite.com) {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }
     if ($host = mysite.com) {
          return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
      }

      listen 80;
      listen [::]:80;

      server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
      return 404;
  }
```

I check and restart Nginx every time. Maybe the Certbot config is interfering. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you haven't moved the files, and you just need to remove `dir1` from the URL, then the only change you need is the `root` directive: `root /var/www/website/dir1;`

Comment: I also want to remove `index.html`. I've tried several of the solutions on here to just do that but still nothing.